# Handlebar get request object

Tags: java, jsp, handlebars.js

1. Request object is populated in servlet.

   ```
   req.setAttribute("Files", fileMap);
   ```
2. In jsp, I could iterate it by below code:

   ```
   <c:forEach items="${Files}" var="file">
       <option value="${file.key}">${file.value}</option>  
   </c:forEach>
   ```

How could I iterate it inside [Handlebar](http://handlebarsjs.com/) template?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a list using the built-in `each` helper. Inside the block, you can use `this` to reference the element being iterated over.

**Try this**

```
<select>
  {{#each Files}}
    <option value={{@key}}>{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Comment: @NabarunDey answer updated. hope it will solve your problem.